# auto calculate without clicking any button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm new for programming and I'm facing one problem.

I have 3 input for values and 1 input for total. What I need is when I change the value in any input total should change automatically.

```
<input type="text" name="Amt" id="amount" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" name="Amt" id="amount" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" name="Amt" id="amount" class="form-control" />
```

And for total I have:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" value="" />
```

And below is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#amount').change(function() {
        $('#total').attr('value', function() {
            var result = 0;
            $('#amount').each(function() {
                result += $(this).attr('value');
            });
            return result;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ID's must be unique, you can't have multiple items with the same id and expect it to work correctly...

Comment: As a first change, make the IDs unique, and use `.val()` instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ids for `amount`. These should be changed to classes. In addition, the value for each amount will be picked out by jQuery as a string, so that needs to be changed to an integer:

```
$('.amount').change(function () {
  var result = 0;
  $('.amount').each(function () {
    result += +$(this).val();
  });
  $('#total').val(result);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/pmwYL/12/).

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct to help future visitors to the site.